# Apply css class to open dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/u5brv/8/

```
$('#nav li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('ul #items').toggle(100);
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('#items').hide();
});
```

I'm trying to change the top menu "top level" css when the dropdown menu is open. I have an active class for it in the CSS, but how can I apply this CSS class to the menu when it has been expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#nav li').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).toggleClass('active')
 $('ul #items').toggle(100);
});

$(document).click(function() {
 $('.active').removeClass('active')
 $('#items').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dLugY/)**

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/u5brv/12/, after clicking it doesnt apply the pink background color class

Comment: @Jimmy: have you checked the fiddle that i have added. You need to add css for active class too.

Comment: Sorry last question, is there a way to apply this only to the very top level. At the moment when you click on an item in the sub list it turns them pink too, whereas I only want the top level to be shown pink or not

Comment: Yes.. you need to modify click event selector to only target top level. here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/JrXV8/

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5brv/15/)**

Use `toggleClass('active')` or `add/removeClass()` functions.

**CSS** :

```
li.active {
    background : red;
}
```

**JS** :

```
$('#nav li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('ul #items').toggle(100);
    $(this).closest('#nav > li').toggleClass('active')
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('#items').hide();
    $('li').removeClass('active')
});
```